# Continue Test execution after Failing test (Android Junit 3)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, junit3

Is it possible to continue Testexcution with Android testing Framework (JUNIT 3) after one single test* Method failed? Currently it stops the whole test execution and does not run further tests.

I'd like it to:

run test 1 successfully

fail test 2

run test 3 successfully

stop

report error of test 2

Comment: What TestRunner are you using, how do you specifiy which tests exactly to run (project, package, class)? Because my tests go through even if single tests fail..

Comment: I use GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner and specify by package name. The problem seems to be, not that the test fails, but that the test terminates and i dont know why. It spawns a thread and wants to wait wor it with countdownlatch. i think that is the problem. But i need to test async call.